Is there a way to override user agent for fetch requests to service workers?
I've always wondered about this and never got it working properly in my extension, but I don't think I'm alone as I've never seen an extension that actually achieved this ...
I overwrite request headers in the following way, from background.js manifest v2:
var OBSHOption = ["requestHeaders", "blocking"];
if (chrome.webRequest.OnBeforeSendHeadersOptions.hasOwnProperty("EXTRA_HEADERS")) OBSHOption.push("extraHeaders");
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details)
{
    if (agent == "Default") return;
    details.requestHeaders = details.requestHeaders.filter(function(elem) { return !elem.name.toLowerCase().includes("sec-ch-ua"); });
    details.requestHeaders.find(function(elem) { if (elem.name.toLowerCase() == "user-agent") elem.value = agent; });

    return {requestHeaders:details.requestHeaders};
}, {urls:["<all_urls>"]}, OBSHOption);

But I still see fetch requests to service workers containing the original user agent ...
UA Header test for example on the following website: https://webbrowsertools.com/useragent/
I believe a google search for "what is my user agent" must be using a similar approach,
although based on network logs they actually request a data:image url, hmm.
Update, I have also tried declarativeNetRequest unless I made a mistake somewhere, it still doesn't override ua in that specific case ...
const delrules =
{
    removeRuleIds: [1, 2, 3, 4]
};

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(delrules);

if (agent == "Default") return;

if (agent == "Chromify")
    agent = navigator.userAgent.replace(/ opr\/[^\s]+| edg\/[^\s]+| vivaldi\/[^\s]+/ig, "");

var types = ["main_frame","sub_frame","stylesheet","script","image","font","object","xmlhttprequest","ping","csp_report","media","websocket","webtransport","webbundle","other"];

const addrules =
{
    addRules:
    [
        { id:1, priority:1, condition: { resourceTypes:types }, action: { type:"modifyHeaders", requestHeaders: [{ header:"user-agent", operation:"set", value:agent }] } },
        { id:2, priority:2, condition: { resourceTypes:types }, action: { type:"modifyHeaders", requestHeaders: [{ header:"sec-ch-ua", operation:"remove" }] } },
        { id:3, priority:3, condition: { resourceTypes:types }, action: { type:"modifyHeaders", requestHeaders: [{ header:"sec-ch-ua-mobile", operation:"remove" }] } },
        { id:4, priority:4, condition: { resourceTypes:types }, action: { type:"modifyHeaders", requestHeaders: [{ header:"sec-ch-ua-platform", operation:"remove" }] } }
    ]
};

chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateSessionRules(addrules);

UPDATE:
There seems to be certain issues with Google services lately when spoofing UA, I believe it has to do with Google doing checks and noticing conflicting UA strings from different requests ...
For example, when I perform a google search for "what is my user agent" the response shows my actual UA. Looking at the headers for google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent they are not modified with declarativeNetRequest at all,- I was expecting them to get altered.
Here's the headers from network log comparing google.com:
Request URL: https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 142.251.33.100:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Platform
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Platform-Version
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Arch
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Model
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Bitness
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-Full-Version-List
Accept-Ch: Sec-CH-UA-WoW64
Alt-Svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Security-Policy: object-src 'none';base-uri 'self';script-src 'nonce-cuZC6Z16kdfnSDv4WwVIDw' 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' https: http:;report-uri https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/gws/web
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin-allow-popups; report-to="gws"
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2024 16:18:29 GMT
Expires: -1
Origin-Trial: Ap+qNlnLzJDKSmEHjzM5ilaa908GuehlLqGb6ezME5lkhelj20qVzfv06zPmQ3LodoeujZuphAolrnhnPA8w4AIAAABfeyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tOjQ0MyIsImZlYXR1cmUiOiJQZXJtaXNzaW9uc1BvbGljeVVubG9hZCIsImV4cGlyeSI6MTY4NTY2Mzk5OX0=
Origin-Trial: AvudrjMZqL7335p1KLV2lHo1kxdMeIN0dUI15d0CPz9dovVLCcXk8OAqjho1DX4s6NbHbA/AGobuGvcZv0drGgQAAAB9eyJvcmlnaW4iOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGUuY29tOjQ0MyIsImZlYXR1cmUiOiJCYWNrRm9yd2FyZENhY2hlTm90UmVzdG9yZWRSZWFzb25zIiwiZXhwaXJ5IjoxNjkxNTM5MTk5LCJpc1N1YmRvbWFpbiI6dHJ1ZX0=
Permissions-Policy: unload=()
Report-To: {"group":"gws","max_age":2592000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://csp.withgoogle.com/csp/report-to/gws/web"}]}
Server: gws
Set-Cookie: 1P_JAR=2024-04-09-16; expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; Secure; SameSite=none
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 0
:authority: www.google.com
:method: GET
:path: /search?q=what+is+my+user+agent
:scheme: https
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Cookie: AEC=AQTF6Hz5v114tgABcpKxnhQSRsg5ZxMJwZ3VjQtGnQ56NAzY0b8QD3HEaw; CONSENT=YES+; NID=513=hdMpMrDkXegilE3BFk8YK52k6rn5ddno2o2FyOi9ndt8iRrvu_mgENqmOFIbzWELVT0Va6MkuZAww4F8XiKp2tx1GWz1g-hu--0jw1VWtwvMjOnG99cgia8ch_kPI9nvQnNU5aArzdRq8tiVhFX2nmiSvj_xBqvVCxBLN6aqkcmPhO0xYfT2Dx-qgfKowgNNelEPMuOe3g; 1P_JAR=2024-04-09-16; DV=I0GdXbXLqMIWEM4dSZxmxyz6x3E67Bg
Pragma: no-cache
Sec-Ch-Ua: "Opera";v="109", "Not:A-Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="123"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Arch: "x86"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Bitness: "64"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Full-Version: "109.0.5097.38"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Full-Version-List: "Opera";v="109.0.5097.38", "Not:A-Brand";v="8.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="123.0.6312.87"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Mobile: ?0
Sec-Ch-Ua-Model: ""
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform: "Windows"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Platform-Version: "15.0.0"
Sec-Ch-Ua-Wow64: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/109.0.0.0
X-Client-Data: CNHqygE=
Decoded: message ClientVariations {
  // Active client experiment variation IDs.
  repeated int32 variation_id = [3323217];
}

vs whatismybrowser.com:
Request URL: https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 3.234.51.167:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept-Ch: SEC-CH-UA,SEC-CH-UA-FULL-VERSION,SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM,SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM-VERSION,SEC-CH-UA-ARCH,SEC-CH-BITNESS,SEC-CH-UA-MODEL,SEC-CH-UA-MOBILE,DEVICE-MEMORY,DPR,VIEWPORT-WIDTH,DOWNLINK,ECT,RTT,SAVE-DATA,SEC-CH-PREFERS-COLOR-SCHEME,SEC-CH-PREFERS-REDUCED-MOTION,SEC-CH-PREFERS-CONTRAST,SEC-CH-PREFERS-REDUCED-DATA,SEC-CH-FORCED-COLORS
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Language: en
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Critical-Ch: SEC-CH-UA,SEC-CH-UA-FULL-VERSION,SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM,SEC-CH-UA-PLATFORM-VERSION,SEC-CH-UA-ARCH,SEC-CH-BITNESS,SEC-CH-UA-MODEL,SEC-CH-UA-MOBILE,DEVICE-MEMORY,DPR,VIEWPORT-WIDTH,DOWNLINK,ECT,RTT,SAVE-DATA,SEC-CH-PREFERS-COLOR-SCHEME,SEC-CH-PREFERS-REDUCED-MOTION,SEC-CH-PREFERS-CONTRAST,SEC-CH-PREFERS-REDUCED-DATA,SEC-CH-FORCED-COLORS
Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2024 16:20:09 GMT
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Referrer-Policy: origin
Server: nginx
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
Vary: Accept-Language
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
:authority: www.whatismybrowser.com
:method: GET
:path: /detect/what-is-my-user-agent/
:scheme: https
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: no-cache
Device-Memory: 8
Dnt: 1
Downlink: 10
Dpr: 1.75
Ect: 4g
Pragma: no-cache
Rtt: 50
Sec-Ch-Prefers-Color-Scheme: dark
Sec-Ch-Prefers-Reduced-Motion: reduce
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Gpc: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Viewport-Width: 1245

The user agent is not touched on google.com for some reason ...
This is a bug in Opera, it's been there a long time, I reported it.
Switched to Brave instead ...

Try using declarativeNetRequest. If it won't work it would be a bug or an intended limitation in Chrome, which you can report in https://crbug.com, assuming there's no such report.

https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40450316 & https://issues.chromium.org/issues/40083897 I don't think this will get corrected anytime soon, I believe it's on purpose for browser fingerprinting reasons, possibly ads, etc.

What's interesting is that when I perform a google search for "what is my user agent" the response shows my actual ua. Looking at the headers for https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+my+user+agent they are not modified with declarativeNetRequest at all!

If you use Opera you must allow your extension to modify the search engine in chrome://extensions.

Yes, I am aware of that and it's already allowed. It seems all requests are modified but not the initial one (and data: ones but that's normal) ... It also doesn't do it on any other hosts. It's quite strange!

Open chrome://policy and check ExtensionSettings value for runtime_blocked_hosts. It may be also a bug in the browser.

Oh wow, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I tried Edge and it's working as expected. Tried Opera once again and it's not. I tried loading chrome://policy but it says invalid URL. This Opera is something else, wow!
